# ssl with both apache and nginx

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, nginx, port

I am running nginx for a static website and an email server, and apache2 for a nextcloud instance on a remote debian 10 server.

I want to use ssl for both. I have set up apache2 to listen on port 8443 instead of 443 for ssl and 8080 instead of 80 for http.

I have successfully applied `certbot` on both servers.

However, if I now go to https://nextcloud.mydomain.com (where apache sits), I still get "Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead". Testing with [this site](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) reveals: The sites I run with nginx are the ones the certificate is valid for. I guess this is because the https-prefix causes my browser to ask port 443, not 8443.

How can I solve this?

Relevant file contents:

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite`:

```
server {

    root /path/to/website;

    index index.html index.htm ;

    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com ;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = www.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;

    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com ;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

`/etc/apache2/ports.conf`:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 9000
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 8443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 8443
</IfModule>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I changed the port ssl_module above to 9000 because making them all 8443 gave me an error.

Start of both `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/nextcloud.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
[...]
```

Start of both `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` and `/etc/apache2/sites-availble/nextcloud-le-ssl.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:8443>
[...]
```

All 4 files have a symlink in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

Comment: If specify a URL with only a domainname, the browser connects to port 80 for HTTP or 443 for HTTPS. To use any other port, you must specify domainname:portnumber in the URL e.g. `http://www.example.com:8080/blah` or `https://www.example.com:8443/bleh`

Comment: hmm, that does work as a workaround, but I don't want the user to have to do that...

Comment: Then you need to set a virtual host that redirects to 443 which will use SSL.

Comment: Wouldn't that conflict with nginx listening on 443 as well?

Comment: Can you show me how to do that? I'm new to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed [this guide](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/run-apache-nginx-haproxy-on-same-server-debian-ubuntu-centos) instead, which worked for me to solve the issue.